# Optional Types?

Tags: freebase, mql

My current query is this:

```
[{
  "type": "/people/person",
  "also:type": "/film/actor",
  "name": "Chuck Norris",
  "/imdb/topic/name_id": null,
  "date_of_birth": null,
  "/film/actor/film": [{
    "film": [{
      "name": null,
      "imdb_id": []
    }]
  }]
}]
```

And this works fine for actors. But I want to return films, given a name or IMDB Name ID etc., for anyone who has worked in films. So directors, products, writers etc.

To do this though, requires lots of different types, like: `executive_produced_by`, `produced_by`, `directed_by` etc.

At the moment, if I pass in Mike Newell, I get no results, as he isn't an actor, but a director among other things.

Any ideas as to how to do this in a single query? I am essentially looking for optional types. e.g. find Mike Newell in `/film/actors` or `/film/directed_by` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What documentation have you consulted so far?  You can use the |= operator to specify multiple IDs, types, etc.  You can use the `optional: true` clause to make a value optional for a property (otherwise, it'll exclude entities which don't have a value for that property).

What have you tried so far and found lacking?

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't fully appreciated that you could used the |= in regards to types. I had actually started to go down the optional, reflection route. Which was actually working quite well, but didn't site nicely with /people/person. Thanks for the help!